# How to detect if content from another server can be loaded into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, x-frame-options

I need to know is there a way to do thing from the title or detect x-frame-origin with JS, Jquery, Ajax. Suggestion: like sending ajax request to the website and get error or something similar... Anyone?

Comment: There's no reliable way. You can't make an AJAX request reliably to a third party site due to the SOP. Why do you need to put external sites in an iframe anyway? The whole reason this is prevented by `X-Frame-Origin` is to stop the common use as phishing attempts.

Comment: Personally i tried for many hours to solve this once for a customer to view full news articles from links in a feed ... and found no reliable way to check if it can load or reliable ways to detect failed loads. An iframe page can also use script to replace your main page with url in iframe